# DC-DC boost converter resets mcu

Tags: microcontroller, pic, dc-dc-converter, boost, inrush-current

Edit: A p-channel mosfet to keep DC boost circuit separated from main circuit until its charged worked like a charm.

I'm trying to build a DC-DC boost converter, controlled by a 200kHz PWM signal generated by a PIC16F887 microcontroller to produce a 10V DC out of a 5V USB port as a part of hobby project.

When I seperately supply my PIC and DC-DC boost circuit, they both work well. But when I try to supply it from same line, [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P81t8.jpg). Periodically, the power circuit's [inrush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwpQS.jpg) current causes a voltage drop, which causes a reset. Then it all starts once again until the next reset.

I just read that on some sources it's called a "hiccup fault," but couldn't find a proper way to deal with it. Any suggestions?

[circuit irl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ1BO.jpg)

[sim circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb7Cr.jpg)

(p.s: The load and output current will also be clocked next. The Zeners are to keep the DC-DC boost from over boosting during no-load situation.)

edit: pictures are inlined on request

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please inline your images. Have you tried just adding more decoupling capacitance to either the boost converter, the MCU, or both?

Comment: I'll try few more. Do you have any suggestions on capacitor type? Maybe an aluminum instead of film and ceramic types?

Comment: You need a CLC or perhaps CRC filter between the 5Vin and the 5V for logic, a CLC filter between the 5Vin and the supply to the power converter and you need a better layout that you may not be able to achieve with a breadboard.

Comment: Try ramping up the PWM slowly and make sure that during boot, there is a gate to source resistor to prevent the MOSFET getting turned on during this period. It's a bit sloppy not having DC feedback from the boost output so you actually regulate the output by altering the PWM - these things can get very crazy open-loop.

Comment: The problem is not PWM but the L-Diode-C path with low ESR

Comment: I just tried connecting the dc-dc boost phase manually with delay and it is working. I guess once the mcu decouple capacitors are charged, they're able to protect the circuit for the transient voltage drop caused by inrush. I'm just planning to add a mosfet switch to activate DC-DC boost with a delay.

It seems less costly than a current limiting circuit since it only requires one GPIO pin and a mosfet. Is there a more elegant option that i can try?

Comment: You could add a series diode before your MCU decoupling caps so at least they don't get drained by the boost converter. If the caps can hold out enough during the boost converter surge then the MCU won't reset. As others have mentioned, you should have input decoupling caps on your boost converter as well. There are also fancier PMOS circuits ideal diode circuits with less voltage drop. You CANNOT use just lone PMOS for this task since, unlike a regular diode, this will only protect against reverse polarity and reverse current from a load dump; Additional circuitry is needed for the PMOS.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507635/how-does-this-multiple-power-supplies-switching-work/507640#507640

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh thanks. Now i learned the term "ideal diode"!